# jQuery toggle show Issue

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
   $('#showhidetarget').show();
   $('a#showhidetrigger').click(function () {
    $('#showhidetarget').toggle(400);
    });
});
</script>
```

I Want this script to be hidden on load and should then be shown everytime, then it can only be hidden if i click on that hide action, because my search form is on toggle, so if someone searches this the form gets closed on the result page which i don't want. Thank you

Comment: Could you clarify this question a bit?

Comment: @m90 Wait i'll explain you again

Comment: the script shows that on page load am showing a div which contains search parameters of my webpage, now the problem is i dont want to show it always, i want to hide on load, and when a user clicks on the anchor tag that div should be shown and when he selects the parameters and searches and when the page loads again with that search results that div should'nt get hidden again now it should be switched to showed unless and until that person clicks on the toggle anchor to hide the div. Thank you

Comment: The code you have written in your question should do just that. That's why there must be something else that is "not working" - Since you are writing "and when he selects the parameters and searches and when the page loads again with that search results that div should'nt get hidden again" it sounds to me as @Nirav Gandhi's solution might be what you are looking for (preventing the reload). Or is it something else?

Comment: Ya even i thought Nirav Gandhi's Solution was perfect and i even aplied to the code but it's still the same. On load it gets hidden again so in short always it should be hidden unless and until a person clicks to search it should be always visible thereon.

Comment: With "always" you mean even on a later visit to the page?

Comment: You said you want to hide it onload. So why do you use `.show()` instead of `.hide()`? You could also set `display: none` as default on your div.

Comment: no that i know dan i've to make use of session n al, jus if a user visits a page it shoul be open fr him hence forth, i guess i've to make use of session/././

Comment: if i use display none again it gets none after the other page is loaded. and i use show so that it does not hide later so that only a user can hide that if he wants and not the default hide because thats important if a person searches that box should'nt closed again on the result page

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you want to do, but as I read the comments you problem could simply be using `.show()` instad of `.hide()`

Now this should hide the div on load.

```
$('#showhidetarget').hide();
```

You could also simply set `display: none` on your div with CSS by default and remove the line `$('#showhidetarget').show();`

I'm using inline CSS as example:

```
<div id="showhidetarget" style="display:none">
</div>
```

Here's an **example** of the **jQuery hide** solution on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/RzHdK/

And this is an **example** of **hiding** the div by default with **CSS**:

http://jsfiddle.net/WSb2Y/1/

**Edit:**

If you want to only hide it by default if you have submitted a form, you could simply do this in PHP:

```
<div id="showhidetarget"<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
                               {
                                   echo ' style="display:none"';
                               } ?>
></div>
```

I formatted it like this above to improve readability. Here's the **one-line-version**:

```
<div id="showhidetarget"<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { echo ' style="display:none"'; } ?>></div>
```